# How can 1 microservice communicate with an instance of elasticsearch in another microservice?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, microservices

I have currently 2 microservices running. One of them has elasticsearch up and running as a container and the data has been pushed to elasticsearch. The other microservice needs to hit an endpoint that fethces the data in elasticsearch and display that data in the browser. The data can be seen in kibana but not when the other microservice hits that endpoint. What could I be doing wrong?

I have tried adding the name of the alias of elasticsearch in the other microservice .env file but still does not seem to communicate with elasticsearch.

```
------microservice 1-----
version: '3.5'
services:
  micro1_php:
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: micro1-app
      DB_CONNECTION: local
      ELASTIC_HOST: mic_elasticsearch
      ELASTIC_PORT: 9200
    networks:
      - default
      - proxynet

  mic_elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.3
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
    volumes:
      - "./storage/es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"  # to be persistant across docker-compose restarts
    networks:
      default: {}
      proxynet:
        aliases:
          - micro.elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

networks:
  proxynet:
    name: custom_network
    external: true







------microservice 2-----
version: '3.5'
services:
  micro2_php:
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: micro2-app
      DB_CONNECTION: local
    networks:
      - default
      - proxynet


networks:
  proxynet:
    name: custom_network
    external: true
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: {
"current_page": 1,
"data": [],
"first_page_url": "/?page=1",
"from": null,
"last_page": 1,
"last_page_url": "/?page=1",
"next_page_url": null,
"path": "/",
"per_page": 10,
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": null,
"total": 0
}